# Avoid anchor tags in URLs when clicking on divs

Tags: html

I have some tabbed content in a page and each tab has an id (#tab1, #tab2 etc).
If I click on a tab then the tab id #tab1 appends itself to the page's URL, making it look like this: www.mysite.com/product.php#tab1

If the user clicks on the browser or mouse back button, the 1st time nothing happens because he's actually returning to the same page but without the #tab1 in the URL and only after the 2nd click, is he taken back to the previous page he was at.

What workarounds are there for this matter? Id actually prefer that clicking on the tab, the #tab1 wasn't appended to the URL in the first place.

Here's some code:

```
<a href="#tab_information">Click for information</a>
<a href="#tech_specs">Tech Specifications</a>

<div id="tab_information" class="tabcontent">tab 1 content</div>
<div id="tech_specs" class="tabcontent">tab 2 content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove hash string from url.

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
  window.location.hash = "";
}
```